# What is the difference between "y=x" and y=tf.identity(x) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am confusing about following code: `y = x` and `y = tf.identity(x)`.
More precisely, I get confusing when I run following code snippets:

code 1:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0.0, name="x")
with tf.control_dependencies([x_plus_1]):
    y = x
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for i in range(5):
        print(y.eval())
```

This will give output: `0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0`

Code 2:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0.0, name="x")
with tf.control_dependencies([x_plus_1]):
    y = tf.identity(x, name='id')
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for i in range(5):
        print(y.eval())
```

The only change is from `y=x` to `y=tf.identity(x)`, but now the results is `1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a Tensor, let's call it `tensor_1`. When you say `y = x` you are saying that the variable `y` has the value of the Tensor `tensor_1`. When you do `y = tf.identity(x)` you are creating a new Tensor, `tensor_2`, which value will be the same as `tensor_1`. But it is a different node in your graph, so the value from `tensor_1` to `tensor_2` has to move. That is why the `with tf.control_dependencies([x_plus_1])` does something in your second code but nothing in the first one. Because in the first code you are not creating any new Tensor which `control_depdendencies` can work with.

To sum up `y = x` makes the variable `y` to point to the same object in `x`, but `y = tf.identity(x)` creates a new object with the content of `x`.